# Expectation of scaled identity plus square Wishart matrix

Tags: random-matrices

I found that $\mathbf H^t\mathbf H$ known as an Wishart matrix,
when each row of $\mathbf H$ is an realization of i.i.d. Gaussian random vector of zero mean and identity covariance matrix ($\mathbf H$ is square).
Then what is the expectation of $(c\mathbf I+\mathbf H^t\mathbf H)^{-1}$?
(Expectation of scaled identity plus square Wishart matrix)

For an invert Wishart matrix of tall size, I found that its expectation is well-known as a scaled identity matrix.
However, $\mathbf H$ is square and an identity matrix is added in this case.